# new keyword in entry script of yii2 framework

Tags: php, frameworks, yii2

To create an instance of a class,we use new keyword. But this line used in index.php of basic/web in yii
Can someone explain this what will this do?

```
(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply creates an [`Application`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-application.html) instance and call the [`run()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-application.html#run()-detail) method on it.

This instance will be accessible via [`\Yii::$app`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-baseyii.html#$app-detail).